# Pasting image into Outlook results in an attachment, rather than inline with content

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, copy-paste

I am pasting an image into an Outlook 2013 email.

I want the image to appear in-line with the text.

Sometimes the image appears as an attachment.

I can force the image to appear in-line by using the insert pictures function, but that's a bit more clicky.

How can I ensure the image appears in-line with the text by a simple copy and paste?

Comment: Just to make it clear, are you talking about copying the _file_ itself or opening the image then copying it (this works tho)?

Comment: I wanted to just insert the image inline without having to open the file first.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is most likely because the image is copied from File Explorer. It will then be added as an attachment instead of embedded in the text.

To verify that your Outlook is working as intended try using the <kbd>PrtScrn</kbd> button and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in Outlook. If the file is added directly then everything is working as intended. There is no way to copy a picture directly from File Explorer and have it embedded.

If you want to embed a picture you have already saved in File Explorer, open it in Paint > Copy the picture > paste into Outlook.

To insert a picture from a file:

1. In an open message, on the Insert tab, click Picture.
2. Browse to locate the picture that you want to insert.
3. Click the picture you want, and click Insert.

NOTE: Microsoft Outlook automatically embeds pictures in a message. You can reduce the size of your email by linking to the picture. In the Insert Picture dialog box, click the arrow next to Insert, and click Link to File.

[image: Insert Image Outlook]

Source: https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Insert-a-picture-or-clip-art-to-an-email-message-in-Outlook-2013-7a0be50d-6034-4b6d-93da-6de876a0510e#__toc301420133

Comment: Note that the "insert" tab only appears when the message composer is popped out. It does not appear when part of the main window.

Comment: If replying to an email I also need to use the Format Text tab (Outlook 2016) and switch from Plain Text to HTML to embed an image. Otherwise Insert/Picture is greyed out. Thought it worth adding this comment.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, but still a bit "clicky":

1. Open your image file with "mspaint" or any other image editor. Copy the image from there and paste into Outlook.
2. Open the image file normally, copy the image and paste into Word - then copy from Word and paste into Outlook.

Comment: Via Word works great for me and is quite practical.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a faster way using Skitch. You can download Skitch for free here...

http://download.cnet.com/Skitch-for-Windows/3000-12511_4-75835711.html

Open Skitch on your desktop.

Now you can drag a in image from file explorer on the Skitch window and will will open to the correct size.

Press Control-C to copy the image from Skitch onto the clipboard.

Switch to your Outlook message and then press Control-V to paste the image embedded into the message.

You can repeat this sequence for multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

Open it with *Internet Explorer*, then copy and paste it on Outlook or use *Snipping Tool* to snap the image and then paste it, it automatically copied to clipboard.

Comment: Using a screenshot tool will ruin the image resolution

Answer (score 0):

A better tweak for me is to use [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) to override the Print Scrn, you can set it to do a partial screen capture which you can size with your mouse and autosave to the clipboard. There's even an option to turn off *capture mousepointer*. So one movement with the mouse and then a ctrl+v into your email.

Comment: Using a screenshot tool will ruin the image resolution

Comment: Very true, I did not get the impression the OP was concerned about res quality, for an email it will more than suffice